# Change a decimal string into a timestamp in Impala

Tags: hadoop, impala

How do you convert a string type like
 t1.updte_timestamp

```
2018-06-02-08.18.45.562742 
2018-05-26-09.18.16.594824
```

into a timestamp? SHOULD RESULT IN:

```
2018-06-02-08.18.45
2018-05-26-09.18.16
```

ETC

The values had been imported from excel and are in STRING-TYPE

I tried:

```
SELECT
 to_timestamp(cast (t1.updte_timestamp as string), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss') as updted_timestamp FROM OLD;
```

but results in NULL for  all values

thank you

Comment: why don't you just take a length=19 prefix out of the timestamp? `substr(value, 1, 19)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `substr` your string and apply to_timestamp as follow

```
select to_timestamp(substr('2018-06-02-08.18.45.562742', 1, 19) , 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss');
```

Make sure you use MM for month and HH for hour in upper case